# Using python coming from matlab - datastructure

Tags: python, matlab, dictionary

I am in the transfer going from Matlab to Python.

In Matlab I have structured my data in structs.
I have some data that I want to manipulate to get a new data set.

e.g.
I have some measurement from a pump. In a specific case there could be 22 points but this is of course different from case to case.

I have the data in a Excel sheet organized in columns. For each data point I have flow (q), Height (h), Torque(torque) and rpm (rpm). I use xlrd to read the data, and this works fine. I create a dictinary with four keys with the values within.

There are some scaling rules that can be used to manipulate a given dataset point. In Matlab I have organized the data in a struct file called hydraulic_data and then there would be 4 vectors i.e. hydraulic_data.q etc.

The first approach was using dict in python. The issue here is that the length of the keys has to defined i.e. you can not add data to the list.

Then I created a empty dict. and filled in with a np.zeros vectors with a length the same as input data. But this does not seem to work for me. A simplified function can be seen below.

```
 def test_for_loop(hydraulic_geometric_scaled):
    import math
    import numpy as np
    no_of_points = len(hydraulic_geometric_scaled['q'])
    zero_vector = np.zeros(no_of_points)
    q = np.zeros(no_of_points)
    h = np.zeros(no_of_points)
    torque = np.zeros(no_of_points)
    rpm = np.zeros(no_of_points)
    hydraulic_scaling_max = {}
    hydraulic_scaling_max['q'] = zero_vector
    hydraulic_scaling_max['h'] = zero_vector
    hydraulic_scaling_max['torque'] = zero_vector
    hydraulic_scaling_max['rpm'] = zero_vector
    rpm_max=6000
    for i in range(no_of_points):
        omega = hydraulic_geometric_scaled['rpm'][i]/60*2*math.pi
        omega_max = rpm_max/60*2*math.pi
        hydraulic_scaling_max['q'][i]= hydraulic_geometric_scaled['q'][i]*(omega_max/omega)
        hydraulic_scaling_max['h'][i]= hydraulic_geometric_scaled['h'][i]*(omega_max/omega)**2
        hydraulic_scaling_max['torque'][i]= hydraulic_geometric_scaled['torque'][i]*(omega_max/omega)**2
        hydraulic_scaling_max['rpm'][i]= omega_max*60/2/math.pi
    return hydraulic_scaling_max
```

this return a hydraulic_scaling_max dictionary but with the same value in each key. In Matlab this work fine but apparently not here. Then I spoke a little with a colleague and he suggested that I should use classes instead.

My questions:
1. Is it the wrong way to go using dict as struct in Matlab? ( I have searched and there seems not to be a clear answer).
2. Why does the code give me the same in all keys?
3. Is classes the best way to go?

Hopefully you can clear things up a little bit so I can get started using Python the best way!

Comment: Can you clarify, "The issue here is that the length of the keys has to defined i.e. you can not add data to the list."? I'm not sure what you're saying here and it might help us find the issue you're encountering.

Comment: @MarkHarley: I am pretty sure he is referring to numpy arrays not being resizable

Answer (score 0):

I will answer your last question first: the best way to  implement this is with a pandas DataFrame.  You can import the excel spreadsheet directly as a DataFrame then add columns as you wish.  So you can do something like this to add columns to the existing data:

```
from math import pi
import pandas as pd

# load the excel file, you will need to adjust this to fit your file
hydraulic_geometric_scaled = pd.read_excel('filename.xls')

rpm_max=6000
omega_max = rpm_max/60*2*pi

omega = hydraulic_geometric_scaled['rpm']/60*2*pi

# you re-use this a lot so it is faster to define it once
factor = omega_max/omega

# copy the columns you want, and apply the scaling factors
hydraulic_scaling_max = hydraulic_geometric_scaled.loc[:,('q','h','rpm','torque')]*[factor, factor**2, 1, factor**2]

# overwrite this column with constant values
hydraulic_scaling_max['rpm'] = rpm_max
```

You could make a class to handle this, but it will be much more complicated since a pandas DataFrame will do what you need out-of-the-box.  Python has a ton of ready-made tools, so if you want to do something always make sure it hasn't been done before by someone else.  There is probably one or more tools already available that will get you 90% of the way there.

For your first question, yes, if you really wanted to use a dict as a MATLAB struct, this is how you would do it.  But you generally don't want to use a dict as a struct, pandas DataFrams and xarray are much better-suited as replacements for MATLAB structs, and are much more powerful than MATLAB structs.

For your second question the reason is that you are defining 5 variables, `zero_vector`, `q`, `h`, `torque`, and `rpm`, but you only ever use `zero_vector`.  In MATLAB, putting that into a struct 4 times will make a copy of the array, so it takes 4 times as much memory but changes to one copy don't affect the others.

However, when you put the 1 array into the 4 python dict values, it doesn't make a copy.  It is better to say that each of those dict keys is a different name for the same array.  So no matter what key you access it by, it will still be altering the same underlying array.  So say you have a name and a nickname, someone calling you by the name and the nickname is referring to the same person.  Same with these arrays.  You would either need to use the 4 separate variables you defined, or use `zero_array.copy()` to make a copy.

The MATLAB approach is a lit bit easier at first, at the expense of hurting performance for large arrays.

Also, although this wasn't a question, the reason MATLAB lets you (seem to) resize matrices while numpy doesn't let you resize arrays is because Python tends to be more up-front about its capabilities.  Strictly speaking neither MATLAB nor Python let you resize arrays.  MATLAB *pretends* to let you resize them, because the language has not truly resizable data structures.  However, what is actually happening is that behind-the-scenes, MATLAB is actually creating an entirely new array each time through the loop, copying all the data to the new array, then releasing the memory on the old array at some point.  This is extremely slow, which is why the MATLAB editor will warn you not to do this.  The same problem occurs when adding new fields to a struct, actually, although you usually have fewer fields so this is often not as much of a problem.

One of the main philosophies of Python is that "you shouldn't lie to your users".  In this case, it means not pretending to do something you can't.  So numpy doesn't pretend to be able to resize arrays when it is really making a copy.  If you want to copy the data to a new array you have to do it explicitly.

Again, the MATLAB approach is a bit easier at first, at the expense of making it hard to tell when you will kill your performance or get out-of-memory errors and the increased risk of causing hard to detect and hard to debug errors.

Also, Python has resizable data structures.  Both the Python list and python dict (and many others data types) can be resized without needing to make a copy.  So there  isn't really a need for numpy to pretend to be something it isn't.